# How to retrieve the value of Meteor users profile attribute?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following attributes in my Meteor.users.profile.

```
"profile" : {
        "annualLeave" : 14,
        "replancementLeace" : 0,
        "medicalLeace" : 7
    }
```

I want to play around with `annualLeave` value.

How can I retrieve the value of `annualLeave` in another variable??

Comment: Not sure I understand you, is this what you want: `let anualLeave = Meteor.user().profile.annualLeave;`?

Comment: @Khang yea similar to that

Comment: @Khang, I just don't want the value of the current user, I have the username, And I want to use it to retrieve the 'annualLeave' value.

Comment: you can either subscibe the users or make a method call as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a meteor call like:

I suggest using ID instead of user name.

```
Meteor.call('getUser','username',(error)=>{ //client
    if(error){
      console.log(error.reason)
  }

})
```

On server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getUser(username){
       Meteor.users.findOne({'username':username}).profile.annualLeave // no recommended
             OR
       Meteor.users.findOne({_id:id})// supply id instead of username
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
var annualL = Meteor.users.find({'username':'your user name'}).fetch()
 console.log(annualL[0].profile.annualLeave);
```